# javascript dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been modding a vbulletin forum.  All I have modded is the css from within the style editor in the bulletin control panel, plus two template files.

What I have found is that one of the javascript dropdowns is no longer working (it definitely was).

The forum is http://forum.selfbuild.com/

Other dropdowns still work ("community" and "forum actions" links in header) so it relates specifically to the "notifications" dropdown menu item, that you see when logged in.

I have reverted the two template files I modded, but the problem still occurs, so it's not that I have blasted some code out of existence.

On mouseover, rather than the browser showing javascript:// in the bottom bar, it shows a URL.

So I have no idea how to fix it - I don't know how to go about tracing a javascript problem.

Any help appreciated.  To log in and see the issue, you can use testuser abc123, and once logged in the notifications menu item appears.

Comment: you should really add the relevant pieces of code in your question. Don't expect people to search for the code in your side

Comment: **Server not found** is your link

Comment: without seeing your code, i say : you have a DOUBLED id, now your javascript do not trigger correctly. Pass your page to a markup-html validator, you'll see what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow: hidden from .toplinks - then your menu will show.

```
.toplinks {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DEDEDE;
color: #417300;
float: right;
font: 11px Arial,Tahoma,Calibri,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
overflow: hidden; <- kill this
text-align: right;
width: 430px;
}
```

This class was basically hiding everything that wasn't already shown, ie. the drop downs.